# Ext.data.JsonStore is not a constructor problem

Tags: extjs

```
    category_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
fields:['category_name','category_id'],
data:Ext.util.JSON.decode('[{"category_name":"SubTemplate 1","category_id":"6"},{"category_name":"Templates","category_id":"5"},{"category_name":"Uncategorized","category_id":"1"}]')
});
```

Gives an error in debug console - Ext.data.JsonStore is not a constructor
and if the defug file is not include it tells 
d is undefined .

So can someone tell me what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use ExtJS 4 then init your classas via Ext.create what will attempt to load the class, if it has not been defined yet or use Ext.require to load classes. 
Go to http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext and read about "create" and "require" method

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Please make sure you are wrapping your code in an `Ext.onReady` call:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    category_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        fields: ['category_name','category_id'],
        data: Ext.util.JSON.decode('[{"category_name":"SubTemplate 1","category_id":"6"},{"category_name":"Templates","category_id":"5"},{"category_name":"Uncategorized","category_id":"1"}]')
    }); 
});
```

In the future, it is best to post your Ext JS questions over on the [Sencha Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/), as you will get a much faster response.